# What would be the method to create a Dynamic Quiz with Logic hooks?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, user-interface

For a site that I'm working on we are wanting to take a specific design pattern that we've seen work well on other sites and replicate it.

[Sample](https://vid.me/LMNE)

The behaviour that we are after (in pseduo code)

```
Question 1
{
if yes go to Question2v1
if no go to question2v2
}
Question 2 version 1
{
if yes go to Question3
if no go to Message with try again button that loops to start
}
Question 2 version 2
{
yes message6
no message 7
}
Question 3
{
if yes go to Question4v1
if no go to question4v2
}
Question 4 version 1
{
if yes message2 with try again button
if no message3 with try again
}
Question 4 version 2
{
if yes message 4
if no message 5
}
```

But with each acting as the Question text simply getting replaced with a short animation as it does so, apart from in the case of message where the text and the responses change.

The content is static, so doesn't need to be obfuscated or anything, as the questions exist as a quick way for the client to self-assess which option fits. All answers are boolean, but have logic hooks depending on which answer.

I've seen some Dynamic Quizzes before, which run from either pure javascript or a jquery plugin (slickquiz) but I wasn't sure on whether they can easily do this behaviour?

Below is a non-functional mock-up. This is two restyled radio buttons split with col-xs-6 class
[image: Current non-functional mockup]
Message:
[image: Message]

code for the style if you'd like:

```
<div class="well-inverse well-lg" >
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h3>To help you decide which method applies to your company &ndash; answer the questions below</h3>
                    <hr>
                    <p>Question 1: Was the Company dissolved more than 6 years ago?</p>
                    <small style="font-variant:small-caps;">Placeholder: Real Content to come later </small>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="funkyradio">
                        <div class="funkyradio-success">
                            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radioY">
                            <label for="radioY">Yes</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="funkyradio">
                        <div class="funkyradio-danger">
                            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radioN">
                            <label for="radioN">No</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've solved this on own actually.

Simply a set of logic loops which detects the ID of the Yes No elements.

And upon the selection of a button, changes the ID of the button based upon response.

so it would be like

```
clicked yes first time
change question based on response
change id of yes/no to match this question
e.g from id="q1Yes" to "q2No"
continue loop until user hits an end of chain.
upon end of chain, restart loop if user presses "try again" button
```

I think my problem was that I wasn't breaking down the problem into small enough parts.